# Анаграмма - как обратить порядок букв в словах в строке, пропуская остальные символы?

Tags: c#

Написать консольное приложение, которое переворачивает все слова во введённой строке.

Например: `"abcd efgh" => "dcba hgfe"`

Все небуквенные символы должны остаться на своих местах.

Например: `"a1bcd efg!h" => "d1cba hgf!e"`

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string str;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите строку: ");
        str = Console.ReadLine();

        if (str != "")
        {
            for (int i = str.Length; i > 0; i--)
            {
                Console.Write(str[i - 1]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Этот код переворачивает всю строку. Дальше не имею понятия как сделать, чтобы небуквенные символы оставались на своих местах.

Как-то так, кто поможет решить это?

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: у меня выводит "abcd efgh" => "hgfe dcba" а должно "abcd efgh" => "dcba hgfe"
Также не знаю как добавить реализацию - Все небуквенные символы должны остаться на своих местах. Например: "a1bcd efg!h" => "d1cba hgf!e"

Comment: А как Вы уже пробовали решить задачу?

Comment: Только то что выше.. дальше не имею понятия как сделать, что бы небуквенные символы оставались на местах..

Comment: Ну вы подумайте, как можно проверить, что на такой-то позиции стоит небуквенный символ

Comment: И напишите отдельную функцию для переворота слова, потому что вам надо будет ещё разделить строку на слова и применить к каждому слову эту функцию

Comment: Вам помог мой ответ? Если да, отметьте его пожалуйста принятым.

Answer (score 0):

Логика разворота слова на месте оставляя спец символы на прежних местах.

```
public string ReverseWord(string word){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
    int i = word.Length - 1;
    foreach (char c in chars){
        if (!char.IsLetter(c)){
            sb.Append(c);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            while (i > 0 && !char.IsLetter(chars[i])){
                i--; // skip non-alphabetic characters
            }
            sb.Append(chars[i]);
        }
        i--;
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: и, кстати, какое отношение к c# имеет java?

Comment: "и, кстати, какое отношение к c# имеет java?" - та ладно) ну вы же профи. Я не подкалываю. Я выложил логику решения и перевести Джаву на Шарп не составит труда.

Comment: Отредактировано. Перевёл с Java на C#

Comment: Ну, если вы приедете на шиномонтаж, вам поменяют колеса, но скажут, что нужно накачать самим, было не очень, согласитесь?)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте разбить на слова, используйте Split(' ') с исходной строкой и работайте с каждым словом, переворачивая слово игнорируя спец знаки и потом вставьте спец. знаки в их исходные позиции.